# How can I get non repeating value from select?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my select statement, it returns duplicate rows (see screen shot). 
 How can I prevent the duplicated rows?

```
SELECT 
   A.TOTAL_PRESENT,
   A."LIMIT",
   A.COST_CENTER,
   A.ID,
   A.PLANT,
   A.BUDGET_YEAR,
   A."VERSION",
   B.BUDGET_YEAR,
   B."VERSION",
   B.PLANT,
   B.CHARGE_CC,
   B.YEAR_DATE_USD
FROM
   CMS.SUM_REPANDMAINT A,
   CMS.V_SUM_REPANDMAINT B
WHERE 
   (A.BUDGET_YEAR = B.BUDGET_YEAR(+)) AND 
   (A."VERSION" = B."VERSION"(+)) AND 
   (A.PLANT = B.PLANT(+)) AND 
   (A.COST_CENTER = B.CHARGE_CC(+)) AND
   (B.USERNAME = '[usr_name]')
```

Output[image]

Comment: You can use `distinct` or `group by`.

Comment: The output in the image doesn't match the posted query. What's the point of that?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate entries mean the filter criteria are not precise enough. One of your data sources produces multiple rows and the WHERE clause doesn't offer sufficient restriction.

You haven't posted any raw data so we can't tell you what additional criteria you need. However you should look at the use of outer joins. Outer joins mean you will return rows if the criteria for the right hand table don't match the criteria of the left-hand table. Why are you doing that?